# Angular 8 Carousel Slide Animations not working

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I have three few images which I need to slide from right to left and next image should transition.

I have all the code required in the [STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/carousel-slideshow)

HTML:

```
<ngb-carousel *ngIf="images" [showNavigationArrows]="showNavigationArrows" [showNavigationIndicators]="showNavigationIndicators">
    <ng-template ngbSlide *ngFor="let image of images">
      <div class="picsum-img-wrapper">
        <img [src]="image" alt="Random slide">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <button>Touch to start</button>
      </div>
    </ng-template>
  </ngb-carousel>
```

Angular animations required for animating the images:

```
animations: [
    trigger('slide', [
      state('previousLeft', style({
        display: 'none',
        transform: 'translateX(-100%)'
      })),
      state('previousRight', style({
        display: 'none',
        transform: 'translateX(100%)'
      })),
      transition('hidden => activeLeft, previousRight => activeLeft', [
        style({
          display: 'block',
          transform: 'translateX(100%)'
        }),
        animate('0.6s')
      ]),
      transition('hidden => activeRight, previousLeft => activeRight', [
        style({
          display: 'block',
          transform: 'translateX(-100%)'
        }),
        animate('0.6s')
      ]),
      transition('activeLeft => previousLeft, activeRight => previousRight,' +
                 'activeRight => previousLeft, activeLeft => previousRight,' +
                 'active => previousLeft, active => previousRight', [
        style({
          display: 'block'
        }),
        animate('0.6s')
      ])
    ])
  ],
```

I wanted it to behave something like this one:
[Another Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-carousel-example-a11xmn?file=src/app/carousel/carousel.component.ts)

Any help would be great in order to achieve that functionality.

Comment: Where you able to make it work?

Comment: @kontenurban no not yet, I will be trying this week again and see.

Comment: looking forward to it!

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this with setTimeout();

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.getData();
} 

private getData() : void {
  
  /*get Image*/
  let subscribe = this.imageService.getImage().subscribe(res => {
      
      this.imageList = res;
       
      setTimeout(() => {
        
        this.setEvent();
      }, 300)
        
    
  }, error => {
    
    console.log('error', error);
  
  }) 
  

}


private setEvent() : void {

  /*something slide event ex) swiper event...*/


}
```

Comment: Hey @realTak would you be able to make it work in the stackblitz provided above.

Comment: @Bob sry bob i don't think ngb-carousel not offer moving events like another slide library.  i found some css tricks but i think you already found these tricks. why don't you use another library

Comment: Yup agreed, thanks for trying and help. I will definitely look around and if I succeed will post it here. Cheers!